# How to Write Files to /dev/null in Powershell and CMD on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, dev-null

In *CMD.exe* I can copy files to */dev/null/* like this:
`copy foo.bar NUL`

But when type:
`rar.exe x fileToBeExtracted.rar NUL`
It will throw a error.

In *Powershell* I can Not copy files to /dev/null/ like CMD:
`copy foo.bar NUL` or `Copy-Item foo.bar NUL` or `rar.exe x fileToBeExtracted.rar NUL`

What can I do to make all above work ?

Comment: What's the point? Are you trying to measure throughput/performance of copy operations on Windows?

Comment: There is no single convention that will work for built-in commands, PowerShell commands and Win32 console applications alike, although they all do have their own ways of specifying a null device. In PowerShell you use `Out-Null`. Win32 commands may or may not work if you pass `\\.\NUL` as the file name, depending on what they do with the file -- `rar` isn't going to work because it wants to create a new file with the specified name, which isn't possible. It would need an option to write to stdout instead, which you can then redirect with `> nul`/`| Out-Null` (I don't know if it does).

Comment: There is no universal syntax. Different command interpreters are different. :-) Both `cmd.exe` and `pwsh.exe` will redirect `stdout` to "nowhere" using `>NUL`. The standard way on PowerShell is to pipe to `Out-Null`.

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen Mostert, that's what I want to know :)